# Letting user download a file + django

Tags: django, file, download

My web app lets a user search through files in a directory and returns a link to files that match a certain time frame.

The user is able to click on any link and view the contents of a file via some URL.

I'd rather have the user be able to click a link and download the file to their system rather than displaying the file contents on a separate page.

Here's what I have so far...

download.html

```
<ul>
{% for file in match %}
    <a href =/media/{{ file }}>{{ file }}</a>
    <br></br>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

we view the file from this view...

```
def xsendfile(request, path):  
    response = HttpResponse()
    response['Content-Type']=''
    response['X-Sendfile']= smart_str(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path))
    return response
```

using this url..

```
url(r'^media\/(?P<path>.*)$', views.xsendfile),
```

I'm not sure how to tackle this or which path to go down

Any guidance is much appreciated! :)

here are my code changes:

```
def xsendfile(request, path):  
    response = HttpResponse()
    response['Content-Type']=''
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename="+path
    response['X-Sendfile']= smart_str(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path))
    return response
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, but you need to set the `Content-disposition` header value, like this:

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename='fname.ext'"
```

Comment: can you check my implementation

Comment: if your implementation is not working after your code changes, maybe your server is not using `mod_xsendfile`, which is necessary to able to do this. If you want to abstract the file sending mechanism and not be tied to a server configuration, you could look up this django library: https://github.com/johnsensible/django-sendfile

Answer (score 0):

Open the file based on the 'path' first:

`with open(path, 'rb') as a:
   response = HttpResponse(a.read())`