# Django: models function for download

Tags: django

views.py

```
def image_downloaded (request, image_id):
    x = get_object_or_404(Image, pk=image_id)
    x.no_of_download += 1
    x.download_photo
    x.save()
    return render (request, 'imagebank/download_successful.html',{'image': x})
```

models.py

```
class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    photo = models.FileField()
    no_of_download = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def download_photo(?????):
    ???????????????????
```

what code should I add in the ?????????, so that once calling the function `image_downloaded` in views.py, the photo file will be downloaded to the user's computer.

Is this possible? Just tell me it wont be possible if it is....><

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer about serving files with django](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50065481/8249301). It might lead you to the appropriate documentation to figure out what you need.

What code have you tried using so far?